# Chrome returns ERR_FAILED for localhost

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

After some experiments with PWA I've encountered a strange issue with Google Chrome only. Every other browser works just fine.

When I load http://localhost the response is: "This site can’t be reached"

The error status is: "ERR_FAILED" (404)

Note:

- "ping localhost" returns 127.0.0.1 (as it should be).
- wget -qO - 'http://localhost' loads the correct content in terminal.
- every other browser loads the correct content.
- the setting in /etc/hosts leads to 127.0.0.1
- if I access the content via IP (127.0.0.1) it loads just fine.
- I have cleared the browsing cache
- the PWA cache seems to be clean.
- The offline box in the network tab is not checked.

If anyone has any ideas on what could cause the issue please share.
The only clue I have is that in the sources tab of the code inspector
there's the content of sw.js (my service worker) but there's nothing to do with it.

Comment: I got NET_ERR_DISCONNECTED but this solution worked for me as well. Popping this down for the search engine links ^^

Answer (score 2):

I came out that the issue was caused by a cookie called ServiceWorker.

After deleting it everything works fine.